# Scraping Table With Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm working on scraping some data for a school project. I'm new to Scrapy and just having a few issues getting going.  I'm trying to scrape data from a table.

I started playing around with the Scrapy shell and was able to generate data via the xpath's i've set in the code below.

However when I go to run

```
scrapy runspider scraper.py -o data.csv
```

I get a spreadsheet but with no data.  The command line does show that 'log_coung/DEBUG': 597.  I just have no idea to figure out how to check what the problem is.  Any help is certainly appreciated.

```
   # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy


class PsaSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'psa'
    allowed_domains = ['psacard.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.psacard.com/pop/t206/']

    def parse(self, response):
        rows = response.css('table.pop-grid tbody tr')
        for row in rows:
            yield {
            'name' : row.css('td')[0].css('span.t206-pop-title::text').extract_first(default='').strip(),
            'variety' : row.css('td')[0].css('span.variety::text').extract_first(default='').strip(),
            'auth' : row.xpath('td[4]//text()').extract_first(default='').strip(),
            'psa1': row.xpath('td[5]//text()').extract_first(default='').strip(),
            'psa1.5': row.xpath('td[6]//text()').extract_first(default='').strip(),
            'psa2': row.xpath('td[7]//text()').extract_first(default='').strip(),
            'psa3': row.xpath('td[8]//text()').extract_first(default='').strip(),
            'psa4': row.xpath('td[9]//text()').extract_first(default='').strip(),
            'psa5': row.xpath('td[10]//text()').extract_first(default='').strip(),
            'psa6': row.xpath('td[11]//text()').extract_first(default='').strip(),
            'psa7': row.xpath('td[12]//text()').extract_first(default='').strip(),
            'psa8': row.xpath('td[13]//text()').extract_first(default='').strip(),
            'psa9': row.xpath('td[14]//text()').extract_first(default='').strip(),
            'psa10': row.xpath('td[15]//text()').extract_first(default='').strip(),
            }
```

my shell says that there is output being delivered, but my csv file just has the headers and no data:

```
2019-04-08 11:54:30 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2019-04-08 11:54:30 [scrapy.extensions.feedexport] INFO: Stored csv feed (596 items) in: psa.csv
2019-04-08 11:54:30 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 223,
 'downloader/request_count': 1,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 70561,
 'downloader/response_count': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 8, 15, 54, 30, 711381),
 'item_scraped_count': 596,
 'log_count/DEBUG': 597,
 'log_count/INFO': 10,
 'response_received_count': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 8, 15, 54, 24, 91920)}
2019-04-08 11:54:30 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Comment: show full error message (log message).

Comment: your code works for me - it gives me some data in csv file. But you put code with wrong indentions - `def` has to be inside `class` - maybe you run with wrong indentions too.

Comment: @furas yeah that was an error on my part, the code is indented

Comment: added my command line output above

Comment: you run with `-o data.csv` but shell show `in: psa.csv` - are you sure you check correct file ?

Comment: yes, i did check the correct file.  looks like i mixed up the name in my question above

Comment: shell shows that it saved some data in file `Stored csv feed (596 items) in: psa.csv`. It can be other mistake: you have the same script in two folders. You run script from one folder but you check result in second folder. You can delete csv file and rename script and run it with new names - maybe it will say that it can't find script with new name.

Comment: so, this was a formatting issue with excel.  the data was actually there, but i couldn't see it oddly enough.  i changed formatting and added a strip to the data and it's all good.  super pumped now that this works!  thank you!     i do have one quick question---the only part that's tripping me up are the dimensions of each row--example, each player has three individual rows. i'm only capturing the top row, but would like to get all ...i''ll update my code above.

Comment: if you have new problem then create new question, don't change this question.

Comment: Ok will do thank you

Comment: I checked - every cell has three elements - one below another - so it looks like three rows. Using `.extract()` instead of `.extract_first(default='')` you can get three strings in every cell. But you get list so you can't use `strip()` directly after `extract()`. You need `'auth' :  [x.strip() for x in row.xpath('td[3]//text()').extract()]` It will save `"24,-,2"` (`auth` for `"Abbaticchio, Ed"`)

Comment: Please close the question as your code is actually working!

Comment: @furas Check out scrapy's documentation regarding Custome Item exporters. You might be looking for the [CsvItemExporter](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/exporters.html#scrapy.exporters.CsvItemExporter)

Comment: @ErickGuerra yes, it can be useful, thank you.

Comment: thanks guys, super helpful

Comment: promise, last question.  is there a way to strip the comma from the number output?  running into issue where the data looks something like this-- (15,000 , 2,000, 3,000)